# Pull data from particular subsite and show on root site

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, sub-site

SharePoint online : I want to develop a portal where content will be in subsite (sub sites will be created based on country name). Now depending on the current logged in user country, data should be pulled from that country subsite

Any thoughts on how will i be able to pass parameter from user profile to **REST** API to pull data from subsite.

Answer (score 2):

To fetch data from sub-site based on country of logged in user, you can use:

- Content Query Web Part (create your own Content Type and query across sub-sites, requires either Publishing site or use the trick to create a Style Library on Top-Level site where you copy all XSLT)
- DataView web part with linked data sources (not so flexible or easy to modify for more dynamic scenarios) http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/display-data-from-multiple-sources-in-a-single-data-view-HA010099144.aspx
- Designer based - change the SPDataSource as used here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdesigner/archive/2007/04/24/spdatasource-and-rollups-with-the-data-view.aspx
- Code-based - SPSiteDataQuery (e.g. http://darrinbishop.com/blog/2007/04/spsitedataquery-for-cross-site-and-cross-list-searches)
- use it with CrossListQueryCache for better performances
- Search Web Part with Site Collection specific scope (e.g. use
  contentType)
- Use Custom JSOM or Rest API to fetch data and display same using HTML content

Now exact answer to your Question:

1. Fetch Current user and Country using JSOM or Rest API
2. Use CAML Query to filter data from Rest Call to subsite[image: CAML Query to filter from Country of user]
3. Use Data received from Rest Call to display the same using HTML

Tutorial Link for Rest API :[Code Project REST API Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/990131/CRUD-Operation-to-List-Using-SharePoint-Rest-API)

Comment: @MonicaJagani Did it work?

Comment: I will updated once i get it working as per the requirements. On high level, it seems i could use one of the methods

Answer (score 1):

Try below rest call
This will get data from the current page location

```
var getTitleURL  =  "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Products')/items?
```

and this will

```
var getTitleURL  =  "/subsitesites/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Products')/items?
```