# Creating a centralised dashboard for Project management

Tags: sharepoint-online, project-summary-web-part

Scenario :

I am using several sub-sites,each having its own task list used for managing a project. I want to have a centralized dashboard at the root of the collection,to demonstrate info on all the sub-sites project.

In short,i want to have an overview of the projects found in sub-sites in the root collection site. Let's say i want to have a project summary web-part that read the task list found in the sub-sites. Any other idea is also welcome.

Can i add a task list that read task from the sub-sites?

Can i add diagrams that illustrate task list found in the sub-sites?

Comment: Please add some questions regarding code or elaborate more to your scenario.

Comment: @PradipR. please see updated question

Answer (score 1):

As it is SharePoint Online, the scenario you have mentioned is quite possible.

**Out of the box(OOB):**

You can use the CQWP web part(Content Query WebPart) which is OOB and does what you want, because you cannot take a list view outside its own site.

So you just add a CQWP webpart and in the properties give the site you want to pull data from and content type as `Task list`,  then it will bring all the items from the task list of the current site and all its subsite. You can also filter more with additional queries in the webpart properties. Example here: [When to use the Content Query Web Part or the Content Search Web Part in SharePoint](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/when-to-use-the-content-query-web-part-or-the-content-search-web-part-in-sharepoint-346a0f48-38de-409b-8a58-3bdca1768929)

**Custom Coding:**

In custom development, you need to do is build up the code with the `REST api` to fetch data from your required subsite. I have done the same for one of my project. There are also other ways like creating provider hosted app and create client webparts in it, but I found this one as easy.

Here is an example to fetch data with `REST api`: [Pull data from particular subsite and show on root site](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/183937/pull-data-from-particular-subsite-and-show-on-root-site)

Once you are able to fetch the data you can use any jQuery plugin or create one to show it in Chart view, timeline view, accordion etc.. Custom coding gives you more flexibility with UI to enhance it.

Comment: I want to show the project summary web part that are in the sub sites in the root collection. Using the content search web part i only get a link to the list(only a small square is shown)

Comment: do you know how i can add JavaScript to that,so that it only changes the color of a row base on certain value

Comment: Yes its possible. here is the useful link: https://davidlozzi.com/2015/11/10/embedding-your-javascript-into-a-sharepoint-page/

Comment: What i want to know is how to target those result in the Display Template ?

Comment: Please post separate question for the same.

Answer (score 1):

Content Search Web Part also can display sub sites list .

https://exploringsp2013.wordpress.com/2014/01/27/display-a-sub-site-list-using-a-content-search-web-part/

For your Scenario ,here is a demo about [Using multiple lists in SharePoint Dashboard Designer](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1020180/Using-multiple-lists-in-SharePoint-Dashboard-Desig)

Comment: any idea how long is the trial and what happens after that?

Comment: do you know how i can add javascript to that,so that it only changes the color of a row base on certain value